# why am i getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, response

Why am i getting this ? and how can i fix it? i m fairly new to coding: i've tried to fix it but i dont know how: here is the code:

ive tried everything i know how to do, unfortunately my knowledge is very sparse, i have taught myself everything so im not fully aware of all the lingo, the website is beatsbycayde.com, essentially im trying to be able to get the character id so i can then use it to link to braytech.org/2/{destinyid]/{characterId}/legend

```js
    // get list of members and populate roster table

var roster = [];

$.when(
  $.ajax({
  url: "https://www.bungie.net/platform/GroupV2/699392/Members/",
  headers: {
   "X-API-Key":"47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
  }
 })
 .success(function(json) {

  if (json.ErrorStatus === 'Success') {

   roster = json.Response.results;

   console.log('Exalted member list:', roster);

  } else {

   alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
   console.log(json);

  }

 })
 .error(function(json) {

  alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
  console.log(json);

 }),

 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny2/2/profile/4611686018429000034/?components=200',
  headers: {
   'X-API-Key': "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
  }
 }).success(function(res) {
  console.log('PS4 stats:', res);
 })

)
.then(function() {

 listMembers(roster);

});

function listMembers(rsp) {

  var
  list = $('.memberList-list'),
  on = 0,
  sortMembers = function(method) {
    // sort by date joined
    if (method = joined) {
      list.find('.member').sort(function(a, b) {
        return ($(b).data('joined')) < ($(a).data('joined')) ? 1 : -1;
      }).appendTo(list);
    } else if (method = username) {
      list.find('.member').sort(function(a, b) {
        return ($(b).data('username')) < ($(a).data('username')) ? 1 : -1;
      }).appendTo(list);
    }
    list.find('.member.online').prependTo(list);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < rsp.length; i++) {

    var
  profile = rsp[i].bungieNetUserInfo,
  member = $('<a></a>');

  // tally up online members
  if (rsp[i].isOnline) {
   on++
  }

  // check for valid profile
  // some users don't have Bungie profiles somehow and it breaks function
    if (typeof profile != 'undefined') {
   // store response data in semantic variables
      var
        name = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.displayName,
        joinDate = rsp[i].joinDate,
        joined = joinDate.substring(0, joinDate.indexOf('T')),
        online = rsp[i].isOnline,
        icon = profile.iconPath,
        memberId = profile.membershipId,
        memberType = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.membershipType,
        destinyId = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.membershipId,
        rank = rsp[i].memberType;
   // configure D OM node and add to page
      $('#destiny-Id').text(destinyId);
    
      member
        .attr({
          'class': 'j-row vertical-center-row member',
          'href': '/player/?bungieId=' + memberId + '&destinyId=' + destinyId + '&joined=' + joined + '&rank=' + rank,
          'title': 'See player profile for ' + name,
          'data-joined' : joined.replace(/-/g, ''),
          'data-username': name,
          'data-online' : 'false',
          'data-searchable' : name,
        })
     
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/"+ destinyId +"/",
  headers: {
   "X-API-Key":"47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
  }
 })
 .success(function(response) {

        if (data.ErrorStatus === 'Success') {

            depth = response.data;

            console.log('Exalted member list:', roster);

        } else {

            alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
            console.log(json);

        }
        //have the line here
        var 
 CharacterId = depth.characters.characterbase.characterId;
    })
     .html(
          '<div class="j-col j-col-1 member-icon"><img src="https://bungie.net/' + icon + '"></div>' +
          '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-name"><h3>' + name + '</h3></div>' +
          '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-joined" data-label="Joined">' + joined.replace(/-/g, '/') + '</div>' +
          '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-status" data-label="Status"><span class="member-online" id="status-' + memberId + '">' + online + '</span></div>' +
          '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-button"><a class="button outline gold full-width">' + 'View Stats' + '</a></div>'+
      '<div class="j-col j-col-3 members-button"> + <a href="https://braytech.org/2/'+ destinyId +'/' + CharacterId +' /legend">In Depth Stats</a>' + '</a></div>'
        );

   if (rsp[i].exalted) {
    member.addClass('exalted')
    .attr({
     'href': '/player/?bungieId=' + memberId + '&destinyId=' + destinyId + '&joined=' + joined + '&rank=' + rank + '&exalted=false'
    })
    .find('.member-name').find('h3')
    .html(name + ' &nbsp;<span class="gold" title="Exalted">&epsilon;</span>');
   }

   member.appendTo(list);

   // indicate online/offline status
      if (String(online) === 'true') {
        $('#status-' + memberId)
        .text('Online')
        .addClass('online')
        .closest('.member')
        .attr('data-online', true)
        .addClass('online');
      } else {
        $('#status-' + memberId).text('Offline').removeClass('online');
      }

      sortMembers(joined); // sort members by join date

    }

  }

 $('#member-count').text(on + ' / ' + rsp.length + ' Members Online');

}
```

Comment: Add a description of what are you're trying to do, what you have tried, what are the results you expect and the whole error message(s) you're seeing. Maybe you can reach the minimum words for the question this way.

Comment: I did , You must have done this while i was retyping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var CharacterId = response.characters.characterbase.characterId;
```

is not inside the `function(response) { ... }` block, therefore it does not have access to the `response` variable, hence the "not defined" error.

Try inserting this line inside the block.

**Edit:** What I meant is:

```
.success(function(response) {

        if (json.ErrorStatus === 'Success') {

            response = response.data;

            console.log('Exalted member list:', roster);

        } else {

            alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
            console.log(json);

        }
        //have the line here
        var CharacterId = response.characters.characterbase.characterId;
    })

//not here
var CharacterId = response.characters.characterbase.characterId;
```

Comment: var {CharacterId = response.characters.characterbase.characterId}: like this? sorry i do not have a formal education in coding everything i do is self taught

Comment: https://beatsbycayde.com/roster/ is the page would you mind running a diag via inspect element or something to show me why its still not working ?  i updated the source code in the original post to be what it is right now